# Delete messages on leave user, discord py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

i want to create a discord bot using discord.py that when a user leave the bot will delete all the messages that user sent in all channels. I know to use the event handlers, but I don t have any idea on how to delete all messages from all channels of one user, I could just put the message id's in a dictionary, but maybe there is a better way.

And as reference is this bot:  https://top.gg/bot/689790568154529792

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
async def on_member_remove(member):
  for c in member.guild.channels:
        await c.purge(limit=None, check=lambda m: m.author==member)
```